# Custom design interface over fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, fullcalendar

I would like to design a custom look and feel over the jQuery plugin FullCalendar. Everything about the FullCalendar implementation fits my needs exactly except the looks.  My question then is: has anyone done this or could anyone offer a solution to do so.

Specifically, I would like to alter the month view with a custom month header, custom day headers with recurring events, and custom events with css background capability.  I do beleive that the custom looking events are fairly well documented so I would like to mainly learn about the others.  I think that simply altering the jquery code to produce different html in the dom should work, but it is so brilliantly dynamic that I have a hard time finding the script that renders the parts I would like to change, even with a the search function in my editor.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I changed the look to look like Google Calendar by modifying the CSS. What specifically are you having an issue with?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Thank you for your response.  I would like to add some custom divs inside the day columns.  For instance, inside the box that says "Monday", I would like to list recurring events underneath the day name.  I would also like to use pretty much a completely custom look and feel. Colors, fonts, icons, everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up completely overhauling the look and feel using css and the existing classes. In places where I needed added content, I modified the .js to generate the content necessary at the same time as the calendar. I found this to be a pretty intuitive calendar to customize once I dug into it.

It was really just a matter of using [Chrome developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) to get the necessary classes and creating my own custom stylesheet.